# SAS Hash join returns unexpected results

Tags: hash, sas

For a project at work we're joining two large datasets together multiple times.  We're using a hash join because it's much faster.  Recently we found that occasionally the HASH join was returning the wrong value but we don't really know why.  A coworker went through and changed a column name in the HASH so we are now using a different name for the returned value and the column name from the HASH table (instead of Liab_ILF_Factor = ROUND(LIAB_ILF_Factor, .001) we're using Liab_ILF_Factor = ROUND(Liab_ILF_Fact, .001) and that seems to be working but just concerned that it happened in the first place and want to make sure we have actually fixed the underlying issue.  What was weird was that the join seemed to correctly match several of the fields (industry, state, weight class, type etc) but would pull the ILF for say 1,000,000 instead of 250,000 which is what it should have pulled.

```
    data liabumuimilffactor (drop=liabumuimilf_factors_dte_key liabumuimilf_factor_state_join veh_wgt_class industry Limit ILF_Bucket Eff_dt Exp_Dt Created_Dt state dte_key
                                  LIAB_ILF_Fact UM_UIM_ILF_Fact PIP_ILF_Fact);
        if 0 Then Set ilf_input Liab_UM_UIM_ILF_Factor;

        if _N_ = 1 then do;
            Declare Hash ILF_Factor_Hash(Dataset:"Liab_UM_UIM_ILF_Factor");         
            ILF_Factor_Hash.DefineKey('state', 'dte_key', 'Veh_Type', 'Veh_Wgt_Class', 'Industry', 'Limit');
            ILF_Factor_Hash.DefineData('ILF_Bucket', 'LIAB_ILF_Fact', 'UM_UIM_ILF_Fact', 'PIP_ILF_Fact');           
            ILF_Factor_Hash.DefineDone();
        end;

        set ilf_input;
        if ILF_Factor_Hash.Find(Key:liabumuimilf_factor_state_join, Key:liabumuimilf_factors_dte_key, Key:Veh_Type, Key:Veh_Wgt_Class_Mapped, Key:IndustryGroup, Key:Liab_Limit) = 0 then do;
            Liab_ILF_Factor = round(LIAB_ILF_Fact, .001);
            Liab_ILF_Bucket = ILF_Bucket;                       
        end;
        else do;
            Liab_ILF_Factor = .;
            Liab_ILF_Bucket = "";
        end;

        if ILF_Factor_Hash.Find(Key:liabumuimilf_factor_state_join, Key:liabumuimilf_factors_dte_key, Key:Veh_Type, Key:Veh_Wgt_Class_Mapped, Key:IndustryGroup, Key:UM_UIM_Limit) = 0 then do;
            UM_UIM_ILF_Factor = round(UM_UIM_ILF_Fact, .001);
            UM_UIM_ILF_Bucket = ILF_Bucket;
        end;
        else do;
            UM_UIM_ILF_Factor = .;
            UM_UIM_ILF_Bucket = "";
        end;

        if ILF_Factor_Hash.Find(Key:liabumuimilf_factor_state_join, Key:liabumuimilf_factors_dte_key, Key:Veh_Type, Key:Veh_Wgt_Class_Mapped, Key:IndustryGroup, Key:PIP_Limit) = 0 then do;
            PIP_ILF_Factor = round(PIP_ILF_Fact, .001);
            PIP_ILF_Bucket = ILF_Bucket;
        end;
        else do;
            PIP_ILF_Factor = .;
            PIP_ILF_Bucket = "";
        end;
    run;
```

Comment: The `Liab_UM_UIM_ILF_Factor` populating `ILF_Factor_Hash` seems a little weird.  Why store all three facts as data items when the 'Limit' key item selects which data item to 'use'.  It's seems like you are doing a 3x3 matrix at that detail level and storing values on the diagonal for retrieval.  Why not one fact value (instead of one value and two non-applicable) for the each limit value ?

Comment: If I understand you're question - the reason that we have different factors for each limit is that different "coverages" have different factors. We could have coverage as an additional key and then have one factor per row if there's some performance enhancement.  We're pulling in the factor tables from a different source and the less manipulation we have to do the better.